# Insert 1000 e-mail into table USERS

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have table USERS with column name, surname and e-mail.

I have already all names and surnames inserted, but no e-mail.

All e-mail are name.surname@email.com

How to insert all e-mail bl taking name from column name and surname from column surname and add @email.com?

thnak you

Comment: That's an `UPDATE` not an `INSERT`

Comment: @sami has the right answer (+1), but caution is required.  Duplicate names, apostrophies as in O'Neil, preferred names (or initials) instead of formal names, suffix as in JR.  In otherwords, this may require some validation.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE Users
SET [E-Mail] = CONCAT(Name, '.', SurName, '@email.com');
```